# Hard reset Canon MF232w i-sensys. Forgot PIN

Tags: printer

How to do a hard reset on Canon MF232w i-sensys?

I forgot my PIN and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Try the default user name Administrator with the default password 7654321.

Comment: can't connect to my wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Press and hold number "4" button
2. While holding the button, turn off the printer using the power switch, do not let go of the button
3. Continue holding it while switching the power back on until it completely boots and is at the menu screen.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!